# How do I add custom ConfigurationSection to Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I've spent a few weeks trying to figure this out, this is a duplicate of a question I asked previously but did not get a response to, so I am refining the question here.

I've created a custom class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;

namespace mssql_gui
{
    public class TestConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public TestConfigInstanceCollection Instances
        {
            get { return (TestConfigInstanceCollection)this[""]; }
            set { this[""] = value; }
        }
    }

    public class TestConfigInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new TestConfigInstanceElement();
        }
        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((TestConfigInstanceElement)element).Key;
        }
    }

    public class TestConfigInstanceElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Key
        {
            get { return (string)base["key"]; }
            set { base["key"] = value; }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)base["value"]; }
            set { base["value"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I've implemented it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="testSection" type="mssql_gui.TestConfigSection"/>
  </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Data Source" value="localhost\SQLEXPRESS"/>
    <add key="Initial Catalog" value="(empty)"/>
    <add key="Integrated Security" value="SSPI"/>
  </appSettings>
  <testSection>
    <add key ="testKey" value="tesValue"/>
  </testSection>
</configuration>
```

and I have tried to access it, I am getting:

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for testSection: Could not load type 'mssql_gui.TestConfigSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I understand that in the type, I should be declare an assembly dll, but I'm confused about that...because in the [official instructions by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx), it says to create a new class for the handler:

> 1. Create a public class that inherits from the
>      System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection class.
> 2. Add code to define the section's attributes and elements.

Adding the class (at least through the visual studio interface) creates a .cs file, not a .dll assembly file, so how to I add that custom class to an assembly file in order to reference it in the `<configSections>` part of app.config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom section in app.config throws error in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116565/custom-section-in-app-config-throws-error-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have problem with resolving what actually your `Assembly` is, since you are only creating `.cs` files that determine `types` that this file hold.

Assembly (in maybe not so accurate shorcut) is just the project you have in your solution. It will get compiled into its seperate assembly - the .dll you mentioned - later on. 
When you add class to any `.cs` file in given project, on compile it will be included in project's assembly.

By default, if you won't provide assembly for `configSection` where its corresponding type should be found, `App.config` defaults to `System.Configuration` assembly - that's where you get your error from, since you've declared your section in your own assembly (== project).

Right click in Visual Studio on your project that holds `App.config` file and choose `Properties` to check its **Assembly name**:

[image]

Then add this name to your `App.config` section declaration. In my example its ConsoleApp1, so I will add it to configuration accordingly:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="testSection" type="mssql_gui.TestConfigSection, ConsoleApp1"/>
</configSections>
```

Comment: Thank you! the problem was that the assembly name was actually "mssql gui" (with a space), I had tried mssql_gui, because that was the namespace that was generated, so the problem really was just the space character. Thanks for showing me where to look for it!

Answer (score 4):

> Ensure that the type attribute of the section element **matches the
>   manifest of the assembly** (ensure that you specify both the correct
>   namespace and type name).

You need to add the name of the assembly (where the type relies) to the type attribute:

*You'll get the name of the assembly from the AssemblyInfo.cs within the project where TestConfigSection class is defined.*

```
 <section name="testSection" type="mssql_gui.TestConfigSection, ASSEMBLYNAME"/>
```

Example asuming your assembly names mssql_gui

```
 <section name="testSection" type="mssql_gui.TestConfigSection, mssql_gui"/>
```

You read it like this:

```
 Configuration config =
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 TestConfigSection mySec = (TestConfigSection)config.Sections["testSection"];
```

See more details at MSDN

[How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, yeah, I had tried mssql_gui, but it was generating a similar error...the problem that I was having was the assembly name itself had a space rather than an underscore, but maybe you can help me with something related to your answer. 

When I use your method, I get "CS0122 'ConfigurationElement.this[ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: where exactly do you get the error? it means that the class/property you want to use is not accesible.

Comment: So the configurationSection class is still defined as above (in the original question). Inside the class in which I want to implement it, I have the following two statements:

    mssql_gui.TestConfigSection s = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("testSection") as mssql_gui.TestConfigSection;

and 

    txtCatalog.Text = s["testKey"].Value;

the error is occuring in the second statement

Comment: what you want is not possible, you will have to use something like (requires using System.Linq;): 
txtCatalog.Text = s.Instances.Cast<TestConfigInstanceElement>().FirstOrDefault(kv=>kv.Key == "testKey")?.Value;
But, have a look on NameValueSectionHandler-Class too!